# How to create a protobuf Message instance given a MessageDescriptor (in dotnet / C#)

Tags: c#, .net, protocol-buffers

Context: C# / dotnet console app using Google.Protobuf 3.6.1

I want to instantiate a new protobuf message object given a MessageDescriptor only, i.e. the message types are not known at compile time.

One way is to do:

```
IMessage message = (IMessage)Activator.CreateInstance(messageDescriptor.ClrType);
```

And from here there appears to be support for runtime manipulation of message objects, e.g.

```
FieldDescriptor fieldDescriptor = messageDescriptor.Fields[0];
fieldDescriptor.Accessor.SetValue(message, 123)
```

A quick search suggests that CreateInstance(Type) is not as efficient as a compile time `new Foo()`, so I wondered if there was built in support that I'm missing, e.g. I was hoping for something like:

```
var msg = messageDescriptor.CreateMessage()
```

or

```
var msg = MessageBuilder.Create(messageDescriptor)
```

Activator.CreateInstance will suffice for my needs (i.e. the slower performance isn't a significant issue in my particular app/context) but I wondered if I'm missing a better/recommended approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately not, as far as I can see at the moment.

Internally (e.g. in `JsonParser`) we call `messageDescriptor.Parser.CreateTemplate()`, but `CreateTemplate()` is an internal method.

I suppose you *could* call:

```
var message = messageDescriptor.Parser.ParseFrom(ByteString.Empty);
```

That would avoid the reflection, and I'm pretty confident it would work, but it's fairly ugly. Worth considering as an alternative...

Comment: ok, thanks Jon. Something to add to a future release maybe? Or is this the result of some bigger picture design decision?

Comment: ok I'll assess the performance of the ParseFrom() approach and I might use that if it's noticeably better. I can live with the ugly code for one line I think so long as it's commented appropriately.

Comment: No particular design decision that I can remember. Feel free to file a feature request :) (You could hide the ugly line behind an extension method on `MessageDescriptor` potentially ;)

Comment: FYI I did some basic performance tests and ParseFrom is marginally faster than CreateInstance() (I'm seeing about 18M/sec vs 16M/sec, on dotnet core 2.2).